# How to dry up database code

Tags: go

I have a database package that contains the following code.

```
package database

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    // required by gorm
    _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
)

type Podcast struct {
    ID       int `sql:"index"`
    Title    string
    RssURL   string `sql:"unique_index"`
    Paused   bool
    Episodes []Episode
}

type Episode struct {
    ID           int `sql:"index"`
    PodcastID    int
    Title        string
    EnclosureURL string `sql:"unique_index"`
    Downloaded   bool
    GUID         string `sql:"unique_index"`
    PubDate      string
}

func DBSession() (db gorm.DB) {
    sqliteSession, err := gorm.Open("sqlite3", cache.db)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    return sqliteSession
}
```

Followed by a bunch of methods that all start with the following code.

```
FindSomethingByID(id int) {
    db := DBSession()
    db.LogMode(false)

    // code
}

FindSomethingElse {
    db := DBSession()
    db.LogMode(false)

    // code
}
```

Calling DBSession and setting LogMode in each func seems bad. I just don't know how to do it better. Could someone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling `gorm.Open` inside every function isn't very efficient: `Open` opens a new  connection pool, and should be called just once ([see the database/sql docs](http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Open), which gorm wraps).

A simple improvement is to establish a global `gorm.DB`, initialise it in `init()`  it from all of your functions - e.g.

```
package database

var db gorm.DB

func init() {
    var err error
    // Note we use an = and not a := as our variables
    // are already initialised
    db, err = gorm.Open("sqlite3", "cache.db")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Turn off logging globally
    db.LogMode(false)
}

FindSomethingByID(id int) {
    err := db.Query("...")
    // code
}
```

This is a quick win and reduces the repetition.

In a larger application it typically makes sense to pass dependencies (like DB pools, config params, etc.) more explicitly by wrapping them in types and creating custom handlers.

You also might initialise the connection in your `package main` and pass the `*gorm.DB` to your `database` package via a `func New(db *gorm.DB)` function that sets a private, package-level variable.

Comment: I rearranged my code like you mentioned above, but i'm getting a error now src/database/database.go:48: cannot assign gorm.DB to db (type *gorm.DB) in multiple assignment

Comment: I've made an edit. `gorm` returns a value and not a pointer, unlike most other packages that wrap database/sql.

Comment: Line 48 is db, err = gorm.Open("sqlite3", "cache.db")

Comment: Don't you open up a new connection pool this way now - going against your own advise by calling init() from every function that needs to conenct to the database?

Comment: @Zahrec No: `init()` is run once on program initialization only (by the runtime). You don't call it yourself.

Comment: Ah, I see. thanks. So every time you want to run a query, you call a function in your database package? You don't make a struct type method for lets say a User type so that you can do User.GetAll()?

Comment: It would make more sense to have a `GetAllUsers() ([]*Users, error)` defined on a UserDB type that embeds the connection. I kept my answer here simple but a better long-term pattern is https://robots.thoughtbot.com/interface-with-your-database-in-go + http://www.alexedwards.net/blog/organising-database-access#using-an-interface - hope those help.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious simplification would be to move the `db.LogMode(false)` call into the `DBSession()` function, and give `DBSession()` a shorter name like `DB()`:

```
func DB() (db gorm.DB) {
    sqliteSession, err := gorm.Open("sqlite3", cache.db)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    sqliteSession.LogMode(false)
    return sqliteSession
}
```

And using it:

```
FindSomethingByID(id int) {
    db := DB()
    // code
}
```

Now there's only 1 line in each of your functions using the db session, one simple function call. You can't really make it any shorter if you always need a new db session.